# Is it possible to launch Google+ iPhone app from within another app?

Tags: iphone, google-plus

I know the url scheme is the only way to do it. Is Google+ having that? And where can I check whether an app has registered url?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your iPhone is jailbroken and you have access to the directory where the Google+ app is (either with a shell or some other app) you can look at the info.plist in the resources dir and the URL scheme is written there. Otherwise you could try downloading the app via itunes on your computer and than viewing the bundle content in finder somehow, the info.plist will be there.

Answer (score 2):

check their `Info.plist` for `CFBundleURLName` and `CFBundleURLSchemes`